# How to move files to a folder while it's known its first letter only through .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to move some files to a folder where the first three letters of the folder are known. How can it be moved to that folder using a batch file.

I tried with the below script:

```
move /-y "C:\test\Softwares Needs\prerequisites\*.txt " "C:\test_dest\softwares\*imp\lib"
```

Here imp is the folder starting three letters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the folder using `for /d`, then use it in `move`:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\test_dest\softwares\imp*") do (
    move /-y "C:\test\Softwares Needs\prerequisites\*.txt" "%%a\lib"
)
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked perfectly !!